# How to retrieve data by using where clause on json column?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql

I have users table in postgres:

```
 Users
 id(character varying)   |  name(character varying)   |  password(character varying)  |  info(json)
  1                          Rohan                        rohan                          {"flag":true, 
                                                                                          "createdBy": 
                                                                                            "admin"}
  2                          Ramesh                       ramesh                         {"flag": false, "createdBy: "admin"}
```

Now, I want to fetch the list of users whose flag value is true. How can I do that?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `->>` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) for this:

```
select *
from the_table
where info ->> 'flag' = 'true'
```

alternatively you can use the `@>` operator:

```
select *
from the_table
where info @> '{"flag": true}'
```